# IIS, PHP, JavaScript, CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iis-7

I working on a new deployment for a Website. this websites runs since 2012.
the server getting changed to newer once.

so I installed IIS over the Server Manager Role. I Use PHP 5.2.

When I open the Site on the Server it showes me the Website but without any JS, CSS or even a button doesn't work. looks like the server doesn't includ some css files or isn't able to load JS. Only reads HTML.

In the Handlermapping I saw that .php, .html, .js or even .css is enabled.

so what im doing wrong that this website doesnt work? witch kind of information do you need to support me.

**Additianal infos:**
- I checked the path and its correct. 
- If I change the index.php to index.html the css would be loadet but not everything.
 
- JS still dont work. 
- I was also testing when the application is in a diffrent directory same result than wehn I change to index.hmtl. 
- In the index.php file I use 3 times JS and the first line JS get called it tells me on the line xx Object expected.

dank you for hellping me

Comment: Is the file path correct? hit F12 while in the web browser and see if the files can be located.

Comment: You need to do the absolute basic 101 debugging, as @TheBetaProgrammer mentioned.  On your browser, look at the error console and the network tab to make sure you aren't getting 404s or other errors.  Once you know which error you are getting, you can update this question with more details.  As it is right now, this question can't be answered with anything more than guesswork.

Comment: I checked the path and its correct. If I change the index.php to index.html the css would be loadet but not everything. JS still dont work. I was also testing when the application is in a diffrent directory same result than wehn I change to index.hmtl. in the index file I use 3 times JS and the first line he tells me on the line xx Object expected.